# Ansible tower cannot see playbook in drop down list

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I am looking for a way to trigger a git pull or a refresh from source control within ansible tower. The situation is that I have added a playbook in source control, however I cannot see it within ansible tower.

Is there a way to trigger a refresh or a git pull ?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According the documenation [Ansible Tower User Guide - Projects](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/projects.html) "_For each project listed, you can get the latest SCM revision (refresh) ... using the respective icons next to each project._".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realised that if the template job is executed, if you go back to the template it now shows any newly added playbook.

What it looks like is that when a template job is executed, it forces a git pull or a refresh behind the scenes.

Comment: I'm glad you found an answer to your problem. Be aware that you can accept your own answer and it lets others know you found a solution

Answer (score 1):

In order to find an updated list of playbooks available to your project you need to refresh your project. This also happens when you run the template job which is why you kind of solved it while running the job.